# Can't select everything in edit mode

Tags: edit-mode, selection-tools

When I'm trying to import this mesh into UE4 (the mesh is a wooden chest). I keep getting missing faces and I've seen people say it's due to Blender and that I should try going in edit mode and select everything with <kbd>A</kbd> then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>, but when I get in edit mode and press <kbd>A</kbd>, it only selects the lid or the base of the chest. The part not selected is underlined red so I'd assume it's related.

Comment: Oops sorry the "all" was not supposed to be part of the title.

Comment: You can use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question to change the contents of your question any time. Please add an image in edit mode (using face selection) that illustrates the issue you are having.

Comment: the "A" key does both "select all" and "unselect all", alternatively: if your mesh has even 1 vertex selected, "A" will do "unselect all"; another "A" press will then "select all". in edit mode, in the top right corner you should see a selected/total ratio, for a simple cube 0/8 means nothing selected, 8/8 means all selected, everything in the middle, a partial selection. Check if this works with a simple cube mesh, then with that one.

Comment: Is this true for other objects too, or only the one you mentioned? Try adding a new object and see if the result is similar. Also, do you have any modifiers on your object? If so, check their settings.

Comment: Also, it's possible you've hit P and separated your object into multiple objects. Go into Object Mode and check to make sure this is not the case.

Comment: Anyone ? Please ?!

Answer (score -1):

You can check, the normals, and also what kind of polygons are better with ue4, quads or triangles.As for the a key, I don't know.Do you use any version under development.The official is 2.78c

Comment: I marked this as 'not an answer' because you give a tip that -in a long search- could possibly lead to an answer. If you answer, make sure there is a specific thing for the person who asked the question to do, that worked in your case when you had a similar problem. You obviously don't know if this works. Ideas, tips and extra questions should be posted as comments.